# Vim doesn't highlight syntax after using "tabe" open multiple files

Tags: vim

I just started to learn Vim, and I found it is very annoying that vim dose not highlight syntax after using `tabe` command to open multiple files. Any solutions for that?

Let me explain more details of this situation.

1. I open file A using vim
2. I type ":tabe file B" to open the second file.

Two files now are opened in a same vim window. However, only file A has syntax highlight, file B does not have syntax highlight. Same situation also happens in ":sp file B".

Comment: You can't use `:tabe` to open multiple files. Do you mean that you used `:tabe` multiple times?

Comment: What's your .vimrc? Does your filetype detection work?

Comment: @IngoKarkat I have no idea about how setting up file type detection. Can you please give a example? I usually work on systemverilog .sv files.

Comment: Do you have `filetype detect on` in your `.vimrc`? Does `:setlocal filetype?` give the expected result on the `:tabedit`ed files?

Comment: @IngoKarkat I will check it and answer you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If that really happens, then you found a bug in vim! But before we jump to any conclusions, my advice is that you first try to debug your vimrc: vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file

BTW, it is very annoying that every newbie vim user tries to make it behave like every other graphical editor. So another suggested read: stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers